# How to send JSON data to a bottle server and store the value in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, curl, post, bottle

I have JSON file data.json that I want to send via curl to a bottle server which then take the values from the file. The problem is that it doesn't store anything in the database. How can I do to store the values I pass through the JSON file?

curl command

```
curl -X POST -i -d @data.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://192.168.1.12:8080/
```

bottle.py

```
@route('/', method='POST')
def index():
    n1 = request.POST.get("maclist", "").strip()
    n2 = request.POST.get("signallist", "").strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", (n1,n2))

    conn.commit()
    return "Items added."
```

data.json

```
{
    "maclist": [
        "a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6"
    ],
    "signallist": [
        "-25"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you read maclist and signallist correctly on the server side ? using bottle ?

Comment: @gachdavit That's exactly what I want to do. I send the post request via curl and I receive 200.

Comment: I added answer, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,,,

## client-side

```
curl -X POST -i -d @data.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://192.168.1.12:8080/
```

## server-side

```
@route('/', method='POST')
def index():
    body = request.body.read().decode('utf8') # read directly HTTP input
    get_dict = json.loads(body) # decode json and get native python dict
    maclist = get_dict.get('maclist', [])
    signallist = get_dict.get('signallist', [])
    data_list = list(zip(maclist, signallist)) # cast to list... You should have same number of elements in both collections (maclist, signallist). Otherwise, zip() function will take collection length which is less.
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO users (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", data_list)

    conn.commit()
    return "Items added."
```

I hope,,, it helps you.

Comment: Also, do not forget that `maclist` and `signallist` are keys and theirs values are `lists` in your case. We are reading just first elements now, you can iterate over it in future and make bulk insertion inside database, or hit multiple times DB. As you want.

Comment: That's true I'm going to need more than one element. The thing is that I'm not going to know how many elements I will have so what would the best approach?

Comment: `executemany()` method is exactly what you want. I updated my answer, check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to add the current date using datetime so I'm using `c.executemany("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO node2 (MAC,SIGNAL,FECHA) VALUES(?,?,?)", data_list, datetime.now())` but I get this error `TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: You should pass ```datetime.now()``` in data_list.
#

```for iterator in data_list:
     iterator.append(datetime.now())```
#
```c.executemany("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO node2 (MAC,SIGNAL,FECHA) VALUES(?,?,?)", data_list)```
#
Learn basics of sqlite api, untill use it.

Comment: If this does not work, maybe in requires ```datetime``` object formatting as ```str```. Just check it. good luck.